# Characterization of closed sets similar to open sets doesn't exist?

Tags: general-topology

In a topological space $X$, it is a simple result (using axiom of choice) that a subset $U$ is open if and only if each of $x\in U$ has an open neighborhood contained in $U$.

I was wondering if we can characterize the closed subsets in a similar manner, *i.e.*, using closed neighborhoods of points of a closed set $K$. The above characterization uses the arbitrary union property of open sets and I reckon that the characterization that I am seeking should use the arbitrary (nonempty) intersection property of closed sets.

However, I am stuck. Any help?

---

Note that I am **not** looking for this characterization: $K$ is closed $\iff$ all points in $X\setminus K$ have an open neighborhood disjoint from $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set $K$ in a topological space $X$ is closed if and only if
$$
\bigcap_{\substack{K \subseteq C \\ C \text{ closed}}} C = K
$$
This uses the arbitrary intersection of closed sets that you wanted.  This just expresses that $K$ is closed if and only if $\overline{K}=K$.  (The left-hand side is just an alternate--and my favorite--definition of the closure of $K$.)  This is the exact dual of the following definition of the interior of a set $A$:
$$
\mathrm{int}A = \bigcup_{\substack{U \subseteq A \\ U \text{ open}}} U.
$$
And, of course, $A$ is open if and only if $\mathrm{int}A=A$.

Alternatively, use the fact that $K$ is closed if and only if it contains all its cluster points.  Thus $K$ is closed if and only if each point $x \in X$ that has the property that every open neighborhood of $x$ intersects $K$ necessarily has $x \in K$.

Comment: Nice. But I don't either of the characterizations fitting my bills. The first one: The similar characterization for the open sets would then be that they are the unions of all the open sets contained inside them; but that doesn't imply (obviously, to me at least) that each point inside an open set has an open neighborhood contained inside that set. [...]

Comment: [...] The second one: It uses open sets again.

Comment: Reread what you wrote:  it does imply that each point is an interior point.  If $A$ is the union of all the open sets inside it, then each point of $A$ necessarily lives in such an open set.

Comment: Oh, yea. I see it now.

Comment: You should not be shocked that some topological properties are best phrased in open sets:  that is all you have in the definition of a topology, anyway.  Also, of course, anything you write down that uses closed sets is secretly just using open sets.

Comment: So, I conclude that the first characterization is the closest we can get to what I was seeking for. Do you agree?

Comment: I don't know that I agree.  It's just the first thing that came to my mind.  Someone else might have a more fitting idea.